# login Page by using django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I am New beginner in python and django...
i want to know how can i create a login form by using  django forms(forms.py)

Answer (score 26):

In your `urls.py` file link to the built in Django login view, and pass in the path to a template you wish to use as the login page:

```
(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {
    'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'
}),
```

And here is an example of what the template my look like (from the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)):

```
{% extends "mybase.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
    {% endif %}

    <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
            </tr>
       </table>

       <input type="submit" value="login" />
       <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
   </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The only thing that appears on the page is the login button. The rest of the form does not display.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. Actually, you don't need to create your own form. Simply use auth module and create your own login template. Read this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: The admin login of django is only meant for development, not for production! I'm not sure if you meant that.

Comment: I mean **auth** module, not admin.