# Django login using form - throws error 'User with username already exists'

Tags: django

I created a login form with fields `username`, `password`.

I am using `FormView` class based view.

During validation, it is throwing error `User with this Username already exists`.

Not getting why its coming. I never called `save`.

I guess its coming during `full_clean()` which is happening in the callstack.

Also, the normal implementation without using forms works, but not getting why I shouldnot use forms.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) says `is_valid()` is called which does the validation

Comment: you may want to provide more code or actual example for this question

Comment: @karthikr yeah, is_valid() does validation. jerry, this is actual example and very clear. One with good Django knowledge will understand what I have written over there.

Answer (score 0):

You only have to subclass the template, not recreate a forms.py and validation by hands:

[login Page by using django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679240/login-page-by-using-django-forms)