# Django: class based views login

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to write my own simple login page but whenever i submit the data it says that `user already exists`

I never called `save`

here is my views.py

```
def login (request):
    form = loginform(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['EMAIL']
            code = form.cleaned_data['code']
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=code)

            if user is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('exam')

    else:
        form = loginform()

    return render(request, 'frontend/login.html', {'form': form})
```

my forms.py

```
class loginform(ModelForm):
    EMAIL = forms.CharField( max_length=30, label = ("Your Email"))
    code = forms.CharField( max_length=30, label = ("Your Code"))
    class Meta:
        model = APPLICANT_DATA
        fields = ('EMAIL', 'code',)
```

I have a similar problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767471/django-login-using-form-throws-error-user-with-username-already-exists) but i can't follow because i'm a bit of a beginner

any pointers, link or a small sample code would really help

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use ModelForm class for your login form's base class because in this case when you call form.is_valid() in your view it's not only validates email and code form fields, but also checks if you can create a new instance of APPLICANT_DATA with email and code that were submitted. As a result your form instance is invalid, that's why you see message "user already exists"

And in your case you only need to validate email and code field, so you should just use forms.Form class as a parent class to you loginform.